# How to bind a new function to an element's onclick event and have it run before all other bound functions

Tags: javascript, dom-events

We want to add functionality to an already existing page using a browser extension. Suppose an element already has functions bound to its `onclick` event. I am binding a new function to the `onclick` of that element. I want to have my function run before all the other functions that have been bound to that event before. I don't want them to begin executing until my function is finished running.

I want to know how I can I bind my new function this way in JavaScript.

Comment: are the events binded with addEventListener or by callback direct affectation? onclick=..

Comment: A simple way to accomplish this would be to have yours run on mouse down since click is onmouseup.

Comment: They are binded with addEventListener.

Comment: The problem with mouse down is I want the other functions to start after my function finishes which may take some time.

Comment: @jimmy I haven't tested this at all, but I think it may work. Try: `element.onclick = function() { doYourAction(); element.onclick(); }` 
Please let me know if this works :-)
Also, if your action involves ajax/anything asynchronous you need to put the `element.onclick()` in it's callback instead so that it finishes first.

Comment: Please note that functions are bound [as event listeners] to elements, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really. Event listeners are usually executed in the order they were attached to elements, and you [can't get those already added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/446892/1048572). If your plugin will not execute before any other listener-adding code, your only chance is to get into the event dispatch process as early as you can.

The best way I can think of is to [add a listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for the [capture phase](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) at the highest point of the dom:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target == theElementInQuestion) // or check for e.target.id...
        // do something with the event like
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true /* sic! */);
```